# how to read json in php website

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

i made a json file for my website with MYSQLi entries (the file will be made every time a user searches, or opens the mobile app)
i looked into the json file via ftp and it has 5 entries with each 3 elements
id, username, email
now, when i try to read it in php i get 0 entries

here is the code i use
btw, i am learning php since 6 months only (stackoverflow has been the best help ever)

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("empdata.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json_a, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo $val;
        echo $key;
        ?><br><br><?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you are trying to decode an already decoded `.json` file

Comment: so i can simply read $string then ?
ill try it now